# Node.js Socket.io client on Flask socket.IO server

Tags: node.js, flask, socket.io

I'm trying to connect a Node.js Socket.IO client to a Python/Flask Socket.IO server.

On the server (Raspberry Pi) runs this project: [Pi-GPIO-Server](https://github.com/projectweekend/Pi-GPIO-Server). This project already has a built-in website which is a socket.io client to access the pins of the Raspberry Pi.
The whole project works well.

Now I'd like to access the socket.io connection from a Node.JS client.

On the server side, I've updated the IP and port of the server to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host="192.168.0.8", port=5000)
```

On the client side my implementation is (as stated in the documentation of the project)

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.0.8:5000', {path: '/', transports: ['websocket']});

socket.on( 'connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('Connected: ');
    console.log(socket);
});

socket.on( 'pins:list', (list) => {
    console.log('List of Pins: ');
    console.log(list);
});
```

Any ideas, why I cannot get a connection?
Is there a limitation of clients in the Flask server? Any special command to send?
Is there a possibility to debug the connection?

Answer (score 0):

@Christoph Please use the below code you should be able to connect...I have Flash server running and Nodejs as a client, It is working fine for me!!!
In my case i am running both server and client in same machine so i used **localhost** in place of **IP address**

```
const socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://192.168.0.8:5000', {
            reconnection: true,
            reconnectionDelay: 10000
          });
    
        socket.on('connect', (data) => {
            console.log('Connected to Socket');
        });
        
        socket.on('event_name', (data) => {
            console.log("-----------------received event data from python flask srver");
        });
    
        //either 'io server disconnect' or 'io client disconnect'
        socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
            console.log("client disconnected");
            if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
              // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
              console.log("server disconnected the client, trying to reconnect");
              socket.connect();
            }else{
                console.log("trying to reconnect agan with server");
            }
            // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
          });
    
        socket.on('error', (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```